# how to generate required output using np.r_ ? how to generate the list for each line connected with points?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, indexing

I have 7 lines connected with random points in specific pattern , and each point is associated with two numbers [2D array].

my work is to generate the list using that 2D array for each line.
like... [3,4,11,12] for 5th line connecting from points 2 to 6.

iam writing a general program therefore i can't mention the coordinates of each line one by one.

i tried using np.r_ but  offcourse it didn't worked for the last three list [3,4,11,12] etc.

generating consecutive numbers was easy.

please refer the picture.

Question will get clear after seeing the figure and the output.

I tried doing these, but unable to conceive the logic to do it.

```
import numpy as np

coordinates_of_points = {1:[0,0], 2:[(2*l)/12,0.5556*h], 3:[(l)/2, h], 4:[(10*l)/12, 0.5556*h], 5: 
                          [l,0], 6:[(2*l)/12, h-3], 7:[(l)/2, h-3], 8:[(10*l)/12, h-3]}

X = { 1:[1,2], 2:[3,4], 3:[5,6], 4:[7,8], 5:[9,10], 6:[11,12], 7:[13,14], 8:[15,16] }

element_connection = { 1:[1,2],  2:[2,3], 3:[3,4], 4:[4,5], 5:[2,6], 6:[3,7], 7:[4,8] }

K = np.zeros((20,20))

roh = np.array([[ 1, 5,  3,  4],
                [ 5,  6,  -4,  8]])


for i in range(4):
    s = roh.T.dot(c).dot(roh)
    empty_list=[]   
    K[np.ix_(a,a)] = K[np.ix_(a,a)] + s
    empty_list.append(K)


for i in X:
    if i % 2 == 1:
        a = X[i]
        index = np.r_[i,i+1,i+2,i+3]
        print(index)


K[np.ix_(index,index)] = K[np.ix_(index,index)] + s
```

[line connected with points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2W8RE.jpg)

```
expected output of print(index)
[1,2,3,4]
[3,4,5,6]
[5,6,7,8]
[7,8,9,10]
[3,4,11,12]
[5,6,13,14]
[7,8,15,16]
```

thankyou so much  !!

Comment: ou generate `index` for each `i` but don't accumulate or save any.  Also `r_` is just a way of using `hstack` or `concatenate`

Comment: [array([ 7,  8,  9, 10]),  ([3, 4], [11, 12]), ([5, 6], [13, 14]), ([7, 8], [15, 16])]
 getting this type of output, how to change the rest of them also in  array ?